# How to set a custom header in Google Cloud Endpoints Javascript Client?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-cloud-endpoints

I can fetch a list of blog posts from Google Cloud Endpoints using the Javascript Client:

```
gapi.client.blog.posts.list().execute(function (resp) {
  console.log(resp);
});
```

But I need to set a custom header value in the Google Cloud Endpoints request that contains a user token (this could be an access token from Facebook). How can I do that using the Javascript Client from Google? I could solve this by not using the Javascript Client from Google, but I would rather use it.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_js
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs

**edit**

It seems I can pass the custom header value like this:

```
gapi.auth.setToken({
    access_token: 'this is my custom value'
});
```

Doesn't seem good practice though. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Had the same problem and ditched JavaScript client for jQuery ([$.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) works fine with Endpoints back end). Any lucky with `setToken`?

Comment: any luck using the headers normally?
this works, but it attaches a string "Bearer" before the token, so i've to do `token = os.getenv('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION').split(" ")[1]`

Answer (score 1):

You can now do this using [gapi.client.request](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#gapiclientrequest), for example:

```
gapi.client.init({
    'clientId': 'YOUR_WEB_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    'scope': 'your_scope'
}).then(function() {
    return gapi.client.request({
        'path': 'http://path/to/your/endpoints/api',
        'headers': { 'mycustomheader': 'myvalue' }
    })
}).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.result);
}, function(reason) {
    console.log('Error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
});
```

See also the [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js) page of the Google API Javascript Client documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the header normally, but fetching the token and adding a variable containing it where you need the token to show.