# Java - Google Cloud Endpoints custom authentication with sessions

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, google-cloud-endpoints

I like Google Cloud Endpoints but I do not want to use the OAUTH2 authentication with Google Accounts.

Instead, my idea is to create my own authentication. Upon successful login, I would like the client to receive a unique session key that it can then use for all authenticated future calls for a given period.

Is there some established way to do this with Google Cloud Endpoints? Or has someone achieved something similar themselves?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In general what you need to:

1) on server side in login method generate session key, store it (indexed) with your custom User object to datastore and return from method;

2) on client side -- store this key as Cookie in browser with expiration time of your choice.

3) send session key (take it from cookie) as custom header ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21183509/how-to-set-a-custom-header-in-google-cloud-endpoints-javascript-client))

4) on server side in all methods (except login()) [add your own Authentificator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25365858/google-cloud-endpoints-and-users-authentication?answertab=votes#tab-top). In authenticate method compare key from request to one you stored.